# New Average with a number deleted

Tags: average

A set of consecutive integers were written down:
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... x-1, x, x+1, ... n-2, n-1, n$
One number, $x$, is deleted. The arithmetic mean of the remaining numbers is $602/17$.
What does "$x$" and "$n$" equal?

I managed to get two equations down:

$x = (\dfrac12)n^2 - (\dfrac{1187}{34})n + \dfrac{602}{17}$
$n = \dfrac{(1187 ± \sqrt(2312x + 1327097))}{(34)}$

After that I got stuck but I managed these conditions:
Since n is an integer
Then...
 The numerator, $1187$ ± $\sqrt(2312x + 1327097)$, must be dividable by $34$
 The square root must be odd
 The radicand, $2312x + 1327097$, must be a perfect square

How would you mathematically prove the answer from here on

Answer (score 5):

For a given $n$, the lowest possible average after removing a value is $n/2$ and the largest possible average is $(n+2)/2$. Since $602/17$ must be between these values, $n=68,69$ or $70$. Since $\frac{\text{total}}{n-1} = \frac{602}{17}$, and the right hand side is in lowest terms, $17 \mid n-1$. Thus, $n=69$, and $x=7$.